# Get different types of data from a csv file and put it in a typedef struct in C++

Tags: c++

I'm beginner in programming and C++.

I have a typedef struct Player with 5 players as an array, like that:

> typedef struct{
>       int id_player;
>       string nickname;
>       char initials[4];
>       int score; }Player;
>   Player players[5];

And I have a csv file with entries like:

1002    Stingger    FMH   12980

where: int id, string, char initials[4], int score
delimited by tabs

I have to get the data from every entry in the csv and fill the players values.

There are similar questions but I don't know how to do it with them and I have to do it as C++ not C. I'm beginner, may be I do nonsense code, but I hope my questions will be useful to others, please don't vote me negative.

I'm trying to do it using an ostreamstring input sequence, but I don't know if it's a good way to do it. I don't know how to do it.
That's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

#include <string>
using std::string;

#include <fstream>
using std::ifstream;
using std::ios;

#include <sstream>
using std::ostringstream;

typedef struct{

    int id_player;
    string nickname;
    char initials[4];
    int score;

}Player;

Player players[5];

int main(){

    int id_player_aux;
    string nickname_aux;
    char initials_aux[4];
    int score_aux;

    string line;

    ostringstream entry;

    entry << id_player_aux << nickname_aux << initials_aux << score_aux;

    ifstream data("test.csv", ios::in);

    while(getline(data, line)){

        entry << line;



    }

    return 0;

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: do you want to get the data from the file and assign it to the player object?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Each entry in the csv to assign to each value of each player, so, with the example, player[1] get from csv:
player[1].id_player= 1002, player[1].nickname = Stingger, player[1].initials = FMH player[1].score = 12980. Next entry, next player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find a duplicate for this but if I understand what you want, you just want a way to store the input from the file to the players array. Research about std::fstream (stands for file stream). This is a sample program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef struct{

    int id_player;
    std::string nickname;
    char initials[4];
    int score;

}Player;

Player players[5];

int main(){

    std::ifstream file("data.csv");

    if(!file.is_open()){
        std::cout << "Could not open the file";
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        file >> players[i].id_player >> players[i].nickname >> players[i].initials >> players[i].score;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        std::cout << players[i].id_player << " "
              << players[i].nickname << " "
              << players[i].initials << " "
              << players[i].score << "\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different solution: It retrieves the player informations line by line and then it stores them into the `struct` tab by tab in `GetPlayerInformation()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

const char TAB = '\t';

struct struct_player {
    int id_player;
    string nickname;
    string initials;
    int score;
};

void GetPlayerInformation(stringstream & stringstream_player, struct_player & player) {
    string string_id_player, string_score;

    getline(stringstream_player, string_id_player, TAB);
    getline(stringstream_player, player.initials, TAB);
    getline(stringstream_player, player.nickname, TAB);
    getline(stringstream_player, string_score, TAB);

    stringstream(string_id_player) >> player.id_player;
    stringstream(string_score) >> player.score;
}

int main() {
    struct_player player;
    string line_player;
    ifstream file_players("players.csv");
    struct_player players[5];

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        if(getline(file_players,line_player)) {
            stringstream stringstream_player(line_player);
            GetPlayerInformation(stringstream_player, players[i]);
            cout << players[i].id_player << ", " << players[i].initials << ", " <<
                    players[i].nickname << ", " << players[i].score << endl;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend overloading `operator>>()` for Player, like this:

```
istream& operator >>(istream& stream, Player& p) {
    stream >> id_player_aux >> nickname_aux >> initials_aux >> score_aux;

    return stream;
}
```

That way, in your main, you can do something like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<MAX_PLAYERS/* in this case, 5 */;i++) {
    data >> players[i];
}
```

Or something to that effect.